# How to get json object from json array using key belongs to one json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json array like this

```
[
{ id: 1, name: "larry" },    
{ id: 2, name: "curly" },
{ id: 3, name: "moe" }
]
```

now i want to get one json object from this array of json objects
ex: 
     i want

```
{ id: 1, name: "larry" }
```

this object from that array of json objects if name=larry . is it possible?

Comment: loop through the array and check the value of the `name` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jquery $.grep() you can search in json data.

```
var jsonData = [
  { id: 1, name: "larry" },    
  { id: 2, name: "curly" },
  { id: 3, name: "moe" }
];

var data= $.grep(jsonData, function(element, index){
  return element.name == 'larry';
});

console.log(data[0].id+ "====" + data[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
var myObj = myJsonResponse[0];

console.log(myObj.id + " " + myObj.name);
```

Or if you wanna find by name:

```
var myObj;

for (var i = 0; i < myJsonResponse.length i++){
  // look for the entry with a matching value
  if (obj[i].name == "larry"){
     //found it
     myObj = obj[i];
  }
}
```